# I just created a new expo cli/react native project, but when I'm trying to use npm start this shows up

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, npm-start, expo

I just created a new expo cli/react native project, but when I'm trying to use npm start this shows up:

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path D:\1Good Tool\Code\Projects\Vinvent/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\1Good      Tool\Code\Projects\Vinvent\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Tony186\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-08-02T17_43_37_041Z-debug.log

Please help, I'm new to all this and have no idea what I'm doing, thank you

Comment: Welcome on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com), please take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). How did you create your `expo` project? Stupid question... But you already checked if `package.json` is present? More information please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your project folder is `Vinvent`

If that's the case then do this

```
cd Vinvent
```

then

```
npm start
```